# How to get the information of something when you have it's "_id" field already in Elasticsearch

Tags: http, curl, elasticsearch, logstash

So I am trying to be able to access information about an object in elasticsearch, when I already have it's unique ID. Here is the current query that I  have:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/packetbeat-2017.03.23/AVr8l8YfyH-VqZ9J_0HZ?pretty'
```

This is the response that I get from it:

```
{
  "error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "No endpoint or operation is available at [AVr8l8YfyH-VqZ9J_0HZ]"
  }
],
   "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
   "reason" : "No endpoint or operation is available at [AVr8l8YfyH-VqZ9J_0HZ]"
},
   "status" : 400
}
```

I know that this index and this ID both exist, any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `_type` in your request. So what you want is...

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/packetbeat-2017.03.23/{_type}/AVr8l8YfyH-VqZ9J_0HZ?pretty'`

and more generally

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index/type/id'`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `_type` in your query.

Index in ElasticSearch is like a database. And Type is like table , and document in ES is like records in table.
Imagine you are trying to retrieve a record from database without specifying which table you need the record from..That's what is happening now.

So your query should be `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/packetbeat-2017.03.23/yourindextypename/AVr8l8YfyH-VqZ9J_0HZ?pretty'`

However, in ES, you can query like below as well,
`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/packetbeat-2017.03.23/_search
{"query":{"term":{"_id":{"value":"AVr8l8YfyH-VqZ9J_0HZ"}}}}'`

I would recommend to install Kibana and Sense so you can query using Sense UI to troubleshoot easily.

kibana- 4.6.3 [Extract from  https://www.elastic.co/jp/downloads/kibana]

Sense (a kibana app)[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/installing.html]

```
After having Kibana installed, access Sense UI

Kibana: http://localhost:5601/

Sense: http://localhost:5601/app/sense
```